Numerical distance between mixing distribution.
Suppose that I have two mixing distributions in a high dimensional space for instance,  $\mathbb{R}^{D}$:
$$
\nu\left(x\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}\pi_{i} \delta_{\mu_{i}}\!\!\left(x\right), \quad \hat{\nu}\left(x\right) =
\sum_{i = 1}^{\large\hat{k}}\hat{\pi}_{i} \delta_{\large\hat{\mu_{i}}}\!\!\left(x\right).
$$
I want to measure the distance between these two distributions numerically.
Theoretically, the Wasserstein Distance is defined as
$$
W_{q} \equiv \left(\inf\,\mathbb{E}\left\vert U - \hat{U} \right\vert_{2}^{q}\right)^{1/q}
$$
where $\inf$ is taken among all joint distributions of random variables $U, \hat{U}$ with marginals $\nu, \hat{\nu}$. However, this distance is hard to trace numerically.
I am wondering if there is a way to measure some distance between these two distributions which is easy to implement in $\tt Python$ language.
